# How do roundup in to a specific number in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

1. 501--> 588
2. 588--> 588
3. 589--> 688

Comment: I'd try a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want the new number to be 12 less than the next 100 (so: -12, 88, 188, 288, etc).

So you'd first off, add 12 to your number, then divide it by 100. That will provide you with a number with decimals that you can now find the ceiling value for. Then you need to multiply that by 100 and subtract 12. Like so:

```
with sample_data as (select -12 num from dual union all
                     select -11 num from dual union all
                     select 88 num from dual union all
                     select 89 num from dual union all
                     select 173 num from dual union all
                     select 189 num from dual union all
                     select 501 num from dual union all
                     select 588 num from dual union all
                     select 589 num from dual)
select num,
       ceil((num + 12)/100)*100 -12 new_num
from   sample_data;


       NUM    NEW_NUM
---------- ----------
       -12        -12
       -11         88
        88         88
        89        188
       173        188
       189        288
       501        588
       588        588
       589        688
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did it!

Answer (score 1):

TRUNC and ROUND functions can be invoked with negative precision. So I get the hundred part and add 88 or 188 depending if the rest of the number is greater than 88 or not.

```
WITH data(val) AS (
    SELECT 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 501 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 588 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1088 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1089 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 589 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    VAL,
    TRUNC(VAL, -2) + CASE WHEN MOD(val, 100) > 88 THEN 188 ELSE 88 END result 
FROM
    data
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the boundary conditions. Also, not clear about the range of values.

Seems like **CEIL** might be  a generic solution. However, based on current values provided in the question, you could do it as following:

You could use a **CASE** expression.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA(num) AS (
  2  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 501 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 588 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 589 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 999 FROM DUAL
  9  )
 10  SELECT num,
 11    CASE
 12      WHEN num < 588
 13      THEN 588
 14      WHEN num > 588
 15      AND num  < 688
 16      THEN 688
 17      ELSE 999
 18    END new_num
 19  FROM DATA;

       NUM    NEW_NUM
---------- ----------
         1        588
        99        588
       501        588
       588        999
       589        688
       600        688
       999        999

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another hack, based on ROUND function.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7286)

**Query**:

```
with sample_data as (select -12 num from dual union all
                     select -11 num from dual union all
                     select 88 num from dual union all
                     select 89 num from dual union all
                     select 173 num from dual union all
                     select 189 num from dual union all
                     select 501 num from dual union all
                     select 588 num from dual union all
                     select 589 num from dual)
select num,
       /*-2 will round to nearest hundred.
       anything above 49 gets rounded up and we want to round up to 12 less than 100, 
       49 + 12 = 61, should be added to original number.
       */
       round(num + 61, -2) - 12 new_num
from   sample_data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7286/0)**:

```
| NUM |  NEW_NUM |
|-----|----------|
| -12 |      -12 |
| -11 |       88 |
|  88 |       88 |
|  89 |      188 |
| 173 |      188 |
| 189 |      288 |
| 501 |      588 |
| 588 |      588 |
| 589 |      688 |
```